# Ball physics, collision detection

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm doing a 2D game with SFML. I'm sure you know that game.It's game with 2 blocks and 1 ball and you have to hit the ball back to the enemy.You can move only up and down with that block.But I've got a lot of problems. I want my ball to behave realistically (with physics), especially when it hits the block.

Second problem is that I don't know how to solve the movement of enemy block because I want to play against computer.Temporarily I've solved it this way:

`if ball is above block:
    move block up
 if ball is under block:
    move block down`

And third one is that I don't know how to check if ball hits the block. I've tried code from SFML page but it didn't work at all.

```
int main()
{
    sf::ContextSettings settings;
    settings.antialiasingLevel = 8;
    float rychlost=5.0f;
    float rychlostKruhX=5.0f;
    float rychlostKruhY=5.0f;
    int okraj=28;
    int vyskaBloku,sirkaBloku;
    const int polomerKruhu=20;
    const int FPS=60;
    const int sirkaOkna=800;
    const int vyskaOkna=600;
    int blockX,blockY;


    RenderWindow window(VideoMode(sirkaOkna, vyskaOkna), "SFML works!",sf::Style::Default, settings);
    window.setFramerateLimit(FPS);

    Texture pozadie;
    if (!pozadie.loadFromFile("background.jpg")){
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    Sprite pozadieSprite(pozadie);


    Texture block;
    if (!block.loadFromFile("block.jpg")){
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    //ball
    CircleShape kruh(polomerKruhu);
    kruh.setFillColor(Color::White);
    kruh.setPosition(sirkaOkna/2-polomerKruhu/2,vyskaOkna/2-polomerKruhu/2);

    vyskaBloku=block.getSize().y;
    sirkaBloku=block.getSize().x;

    Sprite blockSpriteLeft(block);
    Sprite blockSpriteRight(block);
    //pozicia blokov
    blockSpriteLeft.setPosition(okraj,vyskaOkna/2-vyskaBloku/2);
    blockSpriteRight.setPosition(sirkaOkna-(okraj*2),vyskaOkna/2-vyskaBloku/2);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(pozadieSprite);
        //UP
        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Up))
        {
             blockSpriteLeft.move(0, -rychlost);
             blockY=blockSpriteLeft.getPosition().y;
             //ak ide mimo okna
             if (blockY<0){
                 blockSpriteLeft.setPosition(okraj,0);
             }

        }
        //DOWN
        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Down))
        {
             blockSpriteLeft.move(0, rychlost);
             blockY=blockSpriteLeft.getPosition().y;
             //if block is out of window
             if (blockY>vyskaOkna-vyskaBloku){
                 blockSpriteLeft.setPosition(okraj,vyskaOkna-vyskaBloku);
             }

        }
        //movement of ball
        kruh.move(-rychlostKruhX,rychlostKruhY);

        //if ball goes out of window
        if (kruh.getPosition().y<0){rychlostKruhY=-rychlostKruhY;}
        if (kruh.getPosition().y>vyskaOkna-polomerKruhu*2){rychlostKruhY=-rychlostKruhY;}

        //if the ball is behind the block
        if (kruh.getPosition().x < okraj) {break;}
        if (kruh.getPosition().x > sirkaOkna-2*okraj) {break;}

        //movement of right block (PC)
        if (kruh.getPosition().y > blockSpriteRight.getPosition().y) {blockSpriteRight.move(0,rychlost);}
        if (kruh.getPosition().y < blockSpriteRight.getPosition().y) {blockSpriteRight.move(0,-rychlost);}

        //if right block goes out of window
        if (blockSpriteRight.getPosition().y < 0 ) { blockSpriteRight.setPosition(sirkaOkna-2*okraj,0);}
        if ((blockSpriteRight.getPosition().y + vyskaBloku )> vyskaOkna ) { blockSpriteRight.setPosition(sirkaOkna-2*okraj,vyskaOkna-vyskaBloku);}


        window.draw(kruh);
        window.draw(blockSpriteLeft);
        window.draw(blockSpriteRight);
        window.display();

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [You might want to use english variable names](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266563/do-non-english-words-increase-the-probability-of-receiving-downvotes/).

Comment: You may also want to give a better description of "does not work", because we cannot help with that. Describe what you expect to happen, what happens instead and what you tried to fix it.

Comment: That game you're talking about sounds like Pong

Comment: You are right ,sorry I will edit that variables...yes it's something similar to Pong ...I've fixed collision by comparing y and x coordinates of ball to the coordinates of block .... I want ball to behave like in "real life" ,so for example if block is moving down and ball hits it from bottom ,the ball should be reflected in some angle ,also when block is moving up and ball comes from bottom,the ball should be reflected in different angle and I dont know how to calculate these angles with some math and physics ,thank you

Comment: You could use physics engine. Like box2d. But I actually dont know how to implement this with engine.